# Use front camera of iPhone as MacBook's Continuity Camera

Tags: camera, continuity

I am trying to use iPhone's front camera as MacBook's [Continuity Camera](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213244).
It works but it 'forcibly' select the rear camera as Camera.

I went throughout Apple's official documents, no mention at all.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/guide/mac-help/mchl77879b8a/mac
- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT213244

Is front camera supported for this feature? If yes, how may I do so?

Environment:

- iOS 16
- MacOS Ventura 13

Comment: Since you can only use one cameras at a time on the iPhone, I’m speculating that Apple engineers configured this to use the highest quality camera in this mode.  I’ve personally tried as you have, but I didn’t spend a ton of time trying to fix as it wasn’t critical.

Comment: [Multi-cam capture is possible](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/249/), also not sure how DeskView makes use of the cameras. But there doesn't seem to be a way to select the camera in Continuity.

Comment: I as referring to natively.  3rd party apps can do it as well as some Apple apps, but you can’t open the camera app and just use both cameras.  When you tether like this, I’m guessing Aplle wanted to use the best quality camera